# D Windows programming linker error

Tags: windows, linker, d, createwindow

While trying to compile this program with an up-to-date compiler: https://github.com/AndrejMitrovic/DWinProgramming/blob/master/Samples/Chap03/HelloWin/HelloWin.d

I get this linker error: `Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D5win327winuser13CreateWindowWFPxuPxukiiiiPvPvPvPvZPv`

Comment: you need to link the windows library or at least set the link path

Comment: None of the libraries helps, i still get the linking error

Comment: Just to remind you, you need OMF versions of those libraries (if I am not mistaken) if you use DMD.

Answer (score 0):

That's a mangled name, so the problem isn't the Windows libraries themselves... my guess is the dmd_win32.lib file from here https://github.com/AndrejMitrovic/DWinProgramming is needed too.

Try downloading that and adding it to your compile command line. `dmd Hellowin.d dmd_win32.lib`